# How to highlight overlapping strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match, highlight

Let's say we have a string:

"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

You search within that string for **"ove ver"**.

The result should be that the word "**over**" is highlighted.

My code so far:

```js
'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
    .replace(/ove|ver/g, s => s.replace(/\w/g, '<mark>$&</mark>'))
```

The result should be similar to this **[demo](https://regex101.com/r/a8Nm6c/1)** on regex101.

EDIT: Searching for "**o**" shouldn't highlight the string till the next word boundary. Searching for "**o**" should result in: `"The quick br<mark>o</mark>wn f<mark>o</mark>x jumps <mark>o</mark>ver the lazy d<mark>o</mark>g"`

Comment: Your recent edit makes it confusing. Why `o` just highlights `f<mark>o</mark>x` but `ove|ver` highlights the word `over`?

Comment: Sorry for editing. `o` highlights all `o`s within that string. This [demo](https://regex101.com/r/a8Nm6c/1) shows precisely what I mean. Does that help or do you need more details?

Comment: `(?=(o))` results in: `"The quick br<mark>o</mark>wn f<mark>o</mark>x jumps <mark>o</mark>ver the lazy d<mark>o</mark>g"` and `(?=(ove|ver))` results in: `The quick brown fox jumps <mark>over</mark> the lazy dog`

Comment: `ove|ver` means match any alternate so if it matches `ove` it won't match `ver` hence only `ove` will be highlighted in the word `over`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that lookahead assertion but match a full word and highlight it:

```js
const s = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';

var r = s.replace(/(?=ove|ver)\w+/g, '<mark>$&</mark>');

console.log(r);
//=> The quick brown fox jumps <mark>over</mark> the lazy dog
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also search for a partial match using the alternation inside a non capture group `(?:ove|ver)` surrounded by optional word characters `\w*`

```js
const regex = /\w*(?:ove|ver)\w*/g;
const s = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';

console.log(s.replace(regex, "<mark>$&</mark>"));
```